# Why would this defeat Haskell's lazy evaluation?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghci, fold

Today I am writing a small program in Haskell. I found that in ghci's interactive mode, this:

```
take 100 $ foldl (\s a -> s ++ [last s + a]) [0] (1:[6,12..])
```

would hang ghci and make it crash due to out of memory, but this:

```
take 100 $ foldl (\s a -> s ++ [last s + a]) [0] (1:[6,12..606])
```

could run just fine.

Why Haskell's lazy evaluation cannot make the first one run within the memory (3G, BTW)? Or maybe it is ghci's quirk?

Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: The problem is that `foldl` always traverses whole list before producing any output and as such is useless for infinite data structures. You probably want right fold - `foldr`. There's probably more, but this is a good starting point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem is this:

`foldl` has some problems with infinte lists (see [HaskelWiki: Fold](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold))

But if you try to use `foldr` `last s` will be a problem.
Don't know if this is a homework but I think you want to find the solution yourself, so here is a hint: instead of a fold look for a unfold - here is a [example with the fibonaccis](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence#With_unfoldr)

Comment: No, foldl has no problems with infinite lists, it's just that you have a problem with programs that run till the end of time while consuming infinte amounts of memory. :)

Comment: Thanks! This is not a homework, but I am really excited to learn more about Haskell (and that I totally misunderstood foldl and foldr before you answered my question.

Comment: Use `foldr` but switch the arguments of the folding function.

Comment: @is7s have you tried this? (BTW: you can then use `:` instead of `++` but write the evaluation of foldr on paper and look what you do with the **state** ... or run it in GHCi ;)

Comment: @is7s: The problem is that this function is strict in it's first argument (second after `flip`ping). `foldr` can produce something out of infinite list _only if_ the folding function isn't strict in the second argument in all cases.

Comment: Ohh my fault, I didn't notice it will still not terminate. I just meant to say that the arguments should be flipped in order to replace `foldl` with `foldr`.

Comment: The simple solution to this is `scanl`, @ZiyaoWei.